# Sudden Wi-Fi connection drops on a TP-Link TL-WR841N router with approximately 8 devices connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm experiencing a strange problem on my Wi-Fi.

I have TP-Link TL-WR841N router with approx 8 devices connected regularly. While using the internet, sometimes internet suddenly stops working on all devices.

Wi-Fi is still connected on all devices, but pages no longer load for next 5-10 minutes.

Initially I thought that the problem is with my connection to ISP dropping. But, during the last few such downtimes, I tried to access my router's settings page (`192.168.0.1`). Just like the other pages, it didn't load. Router settings should, theoretically load even without an internet connection.

So, it seems the issue is something on the router and not with the ISP.

Can someone advise as to what could be causing the issue?

Here is a scan of the Wi-Fi channels around me. My Wi-Fi router is named “Airpower”:

[image]

Comment: Sounds odd. Can I ask where you live? Do you have a  lot of neighbors and can see tons of Wi-Fi routers when you do a local scan? The reason I ask is I too have experienced similar issues in the past 4 to 5 weeks on my macOS and iOS devices. And I never had issues before. I believe “outages” like this might be caused by so many people working form home since COVID-19 started and channels that used to be safe suddenly being clogged up. Best advice is to get a Wi-Fi scanner that can show you which channels have the most traffic near you and shifting to one that has less traffic.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest firmare? https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wr841n/#Firmware . Use caution... interrupted update can cause harm.

Comment: @JakeGould My WiFi's name is Airpower https://i.imgur.com/ouwNh93.jpg

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm on the latest firmware as per my country's TP-Link website

Comment: @FitzWatson Based on that graph I would say you should change the channel to be locked on channel 1 or 6. While you do not have a lot of routers competing, it seems like channel 11 is pretty clogged up compared to 1 and 6.

Comment: The same thing happened again. Had already switched channel 6

Comment: I have the exact same issue. High pings and packet loss, and even failure to load to the router page. Reconnecting through wifi sometimes restores the problem for a while.  I even have my tl-wr841 running access point mode. When I switch to my other ap, internet connectivity is back immediately. What's so frustrating is that it's so hard te reproduce. Also fixed channel to 6, same issue. Latest firmware indeed. Blaming the router.. :(

Comment: did anyone fix this, my meetings are getting dropped due to this. I am expecting tplink will do something about it....